# 6TB drive in Macpro 2008/2010

Tags: hard-drive, mac-pro

The 6TB drives have changed their mounting hole configuration.
Has any vendor introduced a bracket for the 2008-2010 Macpro (I know these are different from each other, I own both) to handle this? On sites such as OWC, I see warnings, but no solution offered.

For what it's worth this article discusses - [6TB HDDs Causing Problems for System Vendors - But Not the Way You Think](http://www.storagereview.com/6tb_hdds_causing_problems_for_system_vendors_but_not_the_way_you_think)

Older drive and sled up top, and the new (in this case, 8TB Toshiba) below. The side holes match, top, not so much.

[image]

Comment: Glad you told me before i bought one! BTW, empirically, the Pro 3,1 & 4,1 have different drive-holders. Though they look the same, they're not interchangeable, I think the SATA slots come out to be different heights & won't slide in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MPRODBKTLG6/

*NB - OWC Hard Drive Sled / Bracket for Mac Pro 2009, 2010-2012 'Westmere' & 'Nehalem' Models ONLY, (not for Mac Pro 2006-2008 Models)*

> ## OWC Hard Drive Bracket
>
> **for Mac Pro (2009-2012)**
>
> Updated for 2015, the OWC Hard Drive Bracket is the new universal standard to install any SATA hard drive in a Mac Pro tower, including the latest 6.0TB SATA hard drives which feature the new industry-standard mounting screw pattern. With screw mounting holes for all SATA drives, it's the drive sled built for compatibility, flexibility, and ease of use.
>
> Update your trays or use a spare
>
> - Rotate backups
> - Separate storage for individual clients or large projects
> - Simple, inexpensive way to transfer large files between two Mac Pro models
> - Utilize all 3.5" SATA and SAS drives including newer models of 6.0TB and larger capacities utilizing the new screw hole mounting pattern.
>
> *NOTE: These are compatible with the two standards of drive mounting and the screws are shorter than the stock tray so they are also compatible with drives with shorter screw hole depths, such as the Western Digital RE and RED.*

*& apologies for the advertising, no afilliation ;-)*

Comment: Clearly, my search skills are lacking. Strange, OWC gives the warning, but didn't bother linking to the right bracket. Again, thanks. (At least the question might serve as an alert for the issue itself.)

Comment: I've been practising for my black belt in Google-Fu... ;) Seriously, yes, it's odd they don't link to a necessary compatible component. Maybe give them a shout.

Answer (score 2):

WD black 6TB still use old, same mounting hole position so you don't need any 3rd party drive sled. I have 2 6TB WD blacks sitting in 2 drive sled.

For majority 6TB drive (mostly seagate model), you need OWC drive sled mentioned above.

Some of folks have also successfully installed 6TB drive (WD red model) in their mac pro, check #14 post. .

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/6-tb-drives-do-not-work-fit-in-mac-pro-now-what.1825187/

It's nice since WD still retain old mounting hole with 6TB drives. So it's safe to purchase 6TB model of WD black or red. WD green probably same, but i don't know since i don't have that drive.

Answer (score 2):

I have an Early 2008 Mac Pro and new 8TB drives like the one shown in the photo at the top of this page. The two mounting holes closest to the drive's SATA connector fit the sled just fine. The other two, not so much. What to do?

Many years ago, I discovered that the best way to fix something was not to try to duplicate the manufacturer's approach but to come up with a new one based on the tools and materials at hand. So, this is how I cheaply, easily, and securely mounted these drives:

With the sled detached from the drive, remove the two mounting screws and grommets that don't match the drive's mounting holes. The easiest way to do that is to push down on the threaded ends of the screws with the blade of a flat-head screwdriver. That opens two relatively-large grommet holes on the sled.

As a substitute for the thickness and cushioning of the grommets, stick a small piece of similarly-thick tape or, using two-faced tape, other resilient material beside each of the grommet holes, on the side of the holes farthest from the usable mounting screws.

Next, screw the sled to the drive with the two usable mounting screws, making a solid but somewhat floppy connection.

To eliminate the flop, go to your local grocery store and buy some lettuce or other greens that are bundled with a long (about 20"), sturdy, plastic-covered-wire twist tie (alternatively, but potentially not as strong, a single strand of Ethernet wire).

Shape the twist tie into a "U" approximately the width of the drive.

Hold the drive in one hand with the sled-side up and the open end of the sled facing away from you. With your other hand, thread one end of the twist tie beside the drive, into the adjacent grommet hole, and back down beside the drive. Do the same with the other end of the twist tie on the other side of the drive.

Shape the twist tie tight around the sides and bottom of the drive and pull it tight against the cushioning material on the sled. Tie the ends of the twist tie tightly together on the wide, bottom of the drive with a single, full twist. Wind the ends of the twist tie securely under the resulting loop. Trim off the excess.

Tying the twist tie makes a "knot" that can be too big to fit between the bottom of Drive 1 and the top of the fan housing below it. For Drive 1, place the "knot" on what will be the bottom-left corner of the drive when mounted in the computer, so the "knot" fits in the space created by the curved corner of the fan housing.

I tried tying a drive to a sled with other materials and configurations, but none of them worked. Particularly, anything placed on the inside edges of the sled "runners" blocks the sled from sliding onto its mounting bracket.

If necessary to reinstall the removed screws and grommets, wrangle the screws out of the grommets. Ease the grommets into the grommet holes, then push/thread the screws into the grommets.

Happy Early 2008 Mac Pro computing!

Answer (score 0):

WD Blue 6TB drives have the original placement of holes and mount easily in Macpro sleds.

Comment: This answer provides no additional data.